# Read JSON object after user Successfully logged-in

Tags: android, json

I want to use Response Body after user successfully logged in by providing email and password. I tried using bufferReader but i shows NULL.

**Here is what i am doing:**

```
class PostData {
private String response = "", data, userId, dataParsed;
private int responseCode;

String ServerData(String path, JSONObject params) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(path);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
        bufferWriter.write(String.valueOf(params)); //Sending email and Password
        bufferWriter.flush();
        bufferWriter.close();
        outputStream.close();
        responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.print(responseCode);

        if (responseCode == 200) { //now only when email and password are valid read response body

            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String responseBody;

                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                while ((responseBody= bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(responseBody);
                }
                System.out.print("DATA CHECK: " + data); // it shows null here.
                JSONObject root = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                JSONObject jsonObject = root.getJSONObject("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get(String.valueOf(i));
                    userId = (String) JO.get("userId");
                }
                dataParsed = dataParsed + userId;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
Integer passResCode() {
    return responseCode;
}
String passUserId() {
    return userId;
}
}
```

**here is the example of my json response body:**

```
{"data": {"id": "xxxx","ttl": 1209600,"created": "2017-09-20T06:38:31.568Z","userId": 85},"requestStatus":true}
```

i just wanted to read userId from the response body. I am working on this from past 2 days it will be great help if someone helps me :) thanks.

Comment: did you tried debugging your code? are you getting anything in `bufferedReader.readLine()`? what is `data` btw?

Comment: data will contain the json response body. i tried debugging it shows null.

Comment: Try printing log inside your while loop and see if there is any data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
String responseBody;
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

while ((responseBody= bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(responseBody);
}
bufferedReader.close();

// Check if it is still null?
System.out.println(response.toString());
```

Comment: Hey just for clarification, Now i need to parse Json data from `response` right?

Comment: create JsonObject using response.toString()

Comment: hey, i tried to parse userId using Json Object  by passing response.toString(). But it is showing this error in log `W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for 0`

Comment: @KhanStan99 try using Nilesh Rathod's answer to parse!

Answer (score 1):

First, try to replace your loop with

```
 BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
 String line;
 StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
 while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
       response.append(line);
       response.append('\r');
 }
 rd.close();
```

There is a much better way to parse response into Java Object using GSON. [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson/) is a JSON parsing library. A Java serialization/deserialization library that can convert Java Objects into JSON and back.

To use Gson in a Gradle build, add

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

or a later version as dependency to your build.gradle build file

In your ResponseDateModel class, use `@SerializedName("key_name")` as an annotation for each field then there is no need to create a constructor in your model class

key_name is a key in json object.

```
{
   "key_name":"key_value"
}
```

like I have created.

> ResponseDataModel.java

```
public class ResponseDataModel {

@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private Data data;
@SerializedName("requestStatus")
@Expose
private Boolean requestStatus;

public Data getData() {
return data;
}

public void setData(Data data) {
this.data = data;
}

public Boolean getRequestStatus() {
return requestStatus;
}

public void setRequestStatus(Boolean requestStatus) {
this.requestStatus = requestStatus;
}

}
```

Also, create one more model class (say Data.java)

> Data.java

```
public class Data {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("ttl")
@Expose
private Integer ttl;
@SerializedName("created")
@Expose
private String created;
@SerializedName("userId")
@Expose
private Integer userId;

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public Integer getTtl() {
return ttl;
}

public void setTtl(Integer ttl) {
this.ttl = ttl;
}

public String getCreated() {
return created;
}

public void setCreated(String created) {
this.created = created;
}

public Integer getUserId() {
return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
this.userId = userId;
}

}
```

Now parse string `response` from BufferedReaded into `ResponseDataModel.java` class object.

```
try { 
    ResponseDataModel responseDataModel = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(response, ResponseDataModel.class);
}catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> Final Code

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
       response.append(line);
       response.append('\r');
}

try { 
    ResponseDataModel responseDataModel = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(response, ResponseDataModel.class);
String userID = responseDateModel.getData().getId();
}catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}

rd.close();
```